# Applying common (authentication-ish) logic to MVC 5 actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm totally new to ASP.NET and am trying to setup an access control that is, for now, limited to the presence and value of a `Request["key"]` parameter. (At some point, this will change to more advanced authentication.) I have no clue what mechanisms exist for commoning up some sort of access control to only *certain* actions within my controller. Right now, I'm creating a lot of duplicate code that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    if (!IsValidKey(Request["key"]))
    {
        return Redirect("/login");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public ActionResult DoSomethingTotallyDifferent()
{
    if (!IsValidKey(Request["key"]))
    {
        return Redirect("/login");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
// and so on
```

Is there some sort of decorator, some method to override, some configuration where I can common up this behavior and have certain actions simply set their `ViewData` and return their `View()`?

**Update**: I've updated my code to redirect to my login page (decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]`) when not authorized (by adding to my `HomeController` the `[Authorize]` decorator). I have confirmed in the debugger that my authentication is successful, and I am now sending a cookie with:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("myUser", false);
```

Using Fiddler, I can see that my cookie has been sent. I updated my `Web.config` file to use forms authentication:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Home/Index"></forms>
  </authentication>
```

When I navigate to `DoSomethingTotallyDifferent`, I'm immediately redirected to my login page. I see my cookie is sent back to the server, but my action isn't triggered (meaning the auth system is blocking the request due to me being unauthorized/unauthenticated).

Comment: why don't take a look at AuthorizeAttribute in MVC, i think it is ideal for your situation

Answer (score 0):

I think what you possibly could use is a custom action filter.
You can find the details for that here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.100).aspx

There are a few types of custom action filters, the one I would use in your case, would be
OnActionExecuting

That action filter is called before the action method is invoked.

However, wizzardz has a fantastic point and would be the better route to go in the end.

Comment: I am now using `[Authorize]` (see my edit to my original question), but with a cookie set, my MVC app still isn't seeing an authenticated user as being authorized.